# Is there any way to skip hoisting during yarn build?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, dynamics-365

Recently I have updated the node version to 16+. Prior to that, I was able to trigger the `yarn build` command to create the build of my project.

But after installation of node 16+, the yarn build command is throwing the following errors

```
./lib/view-registration.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hoisted/@msdyn365-commerce-modules/wishlist/dist/lib/modules/wishlist-items/wishlist-items.view.js' in 'H:\source\D365_eCommerce\lib'
 @ ./lib/view-registration.js 5:112769-113063
 @ ./node_modules/@msdyn365-commerce/bootloader/entry/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@msdyn365-commerce/bootloader/entry/webpack-public-path.js ./node_modules/@msdyn365-commerce/bootloader/entry/client
```

It seems like it is trying to pick the module from the hoisted folder.

I am new to this concept so have no idea why it is targeting this folder in spite of this it should pick the module from `'@msdyn365-commerce-modules/wishlist/dist/lib/modules/wishlist-items/wishlist-items.view.js'` directly.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

How can I force it to **not** pick the module directly from the **hoisted** folder and use `'@msdyn365-commerce-modules/wishlist/dist/lib/modules/wishlist-items/wishlist-items.view.js'` directly

Thanks,
Aman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue mainly occurred due to the corrupt version of Node.
The only possible solution for this is to make sure that all the dependencies required for Node (16+) are also installed.

We can either download all the dependencies manually or just need to allow the node itself to download all the dependencies at the time of installation.

[image]

Thanks,
Aman